# How to add external javascript file with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an external `JS` file `script.js`

```
(function($) {
// Mega Menu
    $('.toggle-icon').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.toggle-icon').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
});

   // End Mega Menu
    });
```

i want to add this file in my React-Redux App

Can anyone please help me to solve this mystery

Comment: Just include it in the HTML page like any other script?

Comment: @FelixKling let me give a try

Comment: @FelixKling its not working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Export your js code and then import it in your react component.

```
export function toggleIcon() {
  $('.toggle-icon').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).next().slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).find('.toggle-icon').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
      $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can import it in your react component.

```
// custom is the path to the file that holds your js code
import { toggleIcon } from './custom';
```

Then call it in your react component, for example in a react lifecycle method like `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  toggleIcon();
}
```

Another (faster) way is by using `require` in your react component to load in the js code.

`require('./custom');`

That way you load the js code immediately, and you don't need to make an exportable version of your function, it just requires the file.

Answer (score 3):

You need export your file and then import it in your React-app, it's recommended to include these kinds of logics in your React app, but if you really needed, export your function and import in the React Component which you need it, you can name you function as well, something like the below code:

```
export function toggleIcon () {
     $('.toggle-icon').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).find('.toggle-icon').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
}
```

and import it:

```
import {toggleIcon} from 'custom';

toggleIcon(); // call your external function like this
```

Comment: Actually script.js large file  for quick understanding i wrote only one function so in this case how to solve it??

Comment: Yes, you can export the whole thing, you can assign it to var or const to export it as well, if you do it as IFEE, just import it to where you like and it should be working

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `ToogleIcon` instead of `toogleIcon` in the component where you want instance it.

```
import {ToggleIcon} from 'custom';

ToggleIcon(); // call your external function like this
```

and `export default`instead of `export`

```
export default function toggleIcon () {
 $('.toggle-icon').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideUp();
} else {
    $(this).find('.toggle-icon').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown();
}
}
```