# 3rd party javascript not binding to the component after changes route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a 3rd party `contactformcheck.js` that check the contact form. I am following the suggestion in [How to add external javascript file with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702165/how-to-add-external-javascript-file-with-reactjs)

Therefore, I change the code in `contactformcheck.js`

From

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {

    if( $('.form-check').length > 0) {

        $('.form-check').each(function(){

            var form = $(this),
                btn = form.find('.btn-submit');

            btn.addClass('disabled');

            // check form fields for valid or notempty inputs
            function checkInput(){

                form.find('.required-field').each(function(){

                    if($(this).hasClass('mailfield')) {

                        var mailfield = $(this);
                        var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
                        if(pattern.test(mailfield.val())){
                            mailfield.removeClass('empty-field');
                        } else {
                            mailfield.addClass('empty-field');
                        }

                    } else if($(this).val() != '') {

                        $(this).removeClass('empty-field');

                    } else {

                        $(this).addClass('empty-field');
                    }

                });
            }

            // Highlight empty or not valid fields
            function lightEmpty(){
                form.find('.empty-field').addClass('required-field-error');
                form.find('.empty-field').parents('.form-check-line').find('.required-field-error').css({'visibility':'visible'});
                setTimeout(function(){
                    form.find('.empty-field').removeClass('required-field-error');
                    form.find('.empty-field').parents('.form-check-line').find('.required-field-error').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
                },1000);
            }

            //  200ms form fields check
            setInterval(function(){
                checkInput();
                var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty-field').length;
                if(sizeEmpty > 0){
                    if(btn.hasClass('disabled')){
                        return false
                    } else {
                        btn.addClass('disabled')
                    }
                } else {
                    btn.removeClass('disabled')
                }
            },200);

            //  Button submit click
            btn.click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
                    lightEmpty();
                    return false
                } else {
                    form.submit();
                    $('.send-success').fadeIn("300", "linear");
                    form[0].reset();
                    setTimeout(function(){$('.send-success').fadeOut("300", "linear");}, 3000);
                }
            });

        });

    }

});

});
```

To

```
export function checkForm(){
if( $('.form-check').length > 0) {

    $('.form-check').each(function(){

        var form = $(this),
            btn = form.find('.btn-submit');

        btn.addClass('disabled');

        // check form fields for valid or notempty inputs
        function checkInput(){

            form.find('.required-field').each(function(){

                if($(this).hasClass('mailfield')) {

                    var mailfield = $(this);
                    var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
                    if(pattern.test(mailfield.val())){
                        mailfield.removeClass('empty-field');
                    } else {
                        mailfield.addClass('empty-field');
                    }

                } else if($(this).val() != '') {

                    $(this).removeClass('empty-field');

                } else {

                    $(this).addClass('empty-field');
                }

            });
        }

        // Highlight empty or not valid fields
        function lightEmpty(){
            form.find('.empty-field').addClass('required-field-error');
            form.find('.empty-field').parents('.form-check-line').find('.required-field-error').css({'visibility':'visible'});
            setTimeout(function(){
                form.find('.empty-field').removeClass('required-field-error');
                form.find('.empty-field').parents('.form-check-line').find('.required-field-error').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
            },1000);
        }

        //  200ms form fields check
        setInterval(function(){
            checkInput();
            var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty-field').length;
            if(sizeEmpty > 0){
                if(btn.hasClass('disabled')){
                    return false
                } else {
                    btn.addClass('disabled')
                }
            } else {
                btn.removeClass('disabled')
            }
        },200);

        //  Button submit click
        btn.click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
                lightEmpty();
                return false
            } else {
                form.submit();
                $('.send-success').fadeIn("300", "linear");
                form[0].reset();
                setTimeout(function(){$('.send-success').fadeOut("300", "linear");}, 3000);
            }
        });

    });

}


}
```

In `Contact.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ContactInfo from './components/contactInfo';
import ContactForm from './components/contactForm';
import {checkForm} from '../../styles/js/contactformcheck'

class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
   }

 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
  }

  handleLoad() {
    checkForm()
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="b-page-content map-bg">
        <ContactInfo/>
        <ContactForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Contact.defaultProps = {
};

export default Contact;
```

The code above works well when I refresh the page at /contact. The problem occurs when I go to another route via header such as /home and then back to /contact, then the checking is gone. In fact, when the code is working, the mouse cursor will become a *block symbol* which disable the button click on 'Send Message' until the attributes are filled. When it is not working, the mouse cursor is able to click the button of Send Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the route back to /contact, React JS does not actually reload the component, that's why the event is not bonded as the action type is 'load' in `window.addEventListener()` in `componentDidMount()`.

The component only bind the event listener on the first time when the page is loaded. Try other action such as 'mousemove' which will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `DOMSubtreeModified` as action type since 'mousemove' is not working for large screen tablet user.